# UIControlEventValueChanged for UISwitch within UITableViewCell, firing when scrolls into view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Can anyone explain why UIControlEventValueChanged gets triggered when a UISwitch is ON in a tableview cell, but not if it's OFF whilst scrolling?

I have 100+ rows in a tableview with the data being pulled from Core Data, when the UISwitch is OFF UIControlEventValueChanged isn't triggered but if I change the switch to ON when the switch(table row) comes into view it fires UIControlEventValueChanged.

I'm using the following for the cell configuration

```
[customCell.seenSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(seenSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The method seenSwitchChanged, changes a BOOL value in Core Data to match the switch status.

When scrolling through the tableview quickly it stutters and lags when UIControlEventValueChanged is fired. I'm guessing because the tableview is looking up data from CoreData and seenSwitchChanged is also trying to access CoreData

If I comment out the above line the tableview scrolls smoothly.

Hope that explanation is clear enough.

Many Thanks

Matt

**EDIT**

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ECCustomCell *customCell = (ECCustomCell *)cell;
    ECPerson *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    customCell.name.text = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
    customCell.seenSwitch.on = [[person valueForKey:@"seen"] boolValue];

    [customCell.seenSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(seenSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation

Comment: @Paul.s added implementation to the post. Thanks

Comment: Where are your cells actually being created I'm not seeing it in the code you have posted

Comment: @Paul.s I'm using a Storyboard and prototype cells. Thats all the code I have for creating and configuring cells.

Comment: did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the dequeue result for nil and allocate a cell if that happens.  I also think your theory is correct about setting the switch on the fly.  A remedy might be to use a scroll view delegate hook on the table view to more lazily set the values of just visible switches.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self setMySwitches];
}

- (void)setMySwitches {

    for (NSIndexPath *path in [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
        // like your cell config logic
    }
}
```